# Minimal repo changes for adding an R script to a python poetry/GH actions repo

Tags: r, github-actions, r-package, python-poetry

I contribute to https://github.com/microbiomedata/sample-annotator. It's a python poetry repo and uses GH actions for CI/CD.

I would like to add one R script that uses the  [neonUtilities package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/neonUtilities/index.html). That package replaces numerous REST API calls and parses with a single command for creating data frames about environmental observations across time and sites.

What's the minimal additional configuration I should add for automating the installation of the neonUtilities package and running a few lines of code that use its methods?

Comment: Start writing code, and then if you encounter an issue ask a question. Right now, you are showing us nothing, so there is nothing we can help with. -- Why do you want to package R code with tools made to package Python code? Is that really what you want to do? Doesn't the R ecosystem have their own packaging tools? What are we looking at here?

Comment: OK, thanks for the tough love. I'm doing more research now and will either close or update the question.

Answer (score 0):

At least under GH Actions automation, my needs are met by

- r-lib/actions/setup-r
- r-lib/actions/setup-r-dependencies

from https://github.com/r-lib/actions

I can run the R code with  `run: Rscript`... lines in the GH action file

I will also want to do local automation with a Makefile eventually.